# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 after GC freed

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection

I'm getting randomly application crashes in android, looking at my logcat the only thing in common that I can see is that the garbage collector was called just before.

The app is developped in Kotlin and the only OS we have the issue in on android 5.1.1

Any help is appreciated

Here's a couple of example:

```
01-18 08:38:53.925 I/art     (28860): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 167858(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 11MB/19MB, paused 1.311ms total 116.690ms

01-18 08:38:53.929 F/libc    (28860): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f56398 passed to dlfree
01-18 08:38:53.929 F/libc    (28860): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 28871 (FinalizerDaemon)

-----------------------------------

01-18 08:49:19.938 I/art     (17009): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 162217(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 11MB/19MB, paused 1.522ms total 100.354ms

01-18 08:49:19.944 F/libc    (17009): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb passed to dlfree
01-18 08:49:19.945 F/libc    (17009): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 17020 (FinalizerDaemon)
_____________________


01-18 10:16:31.657 I/art     ( 3922): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 176873(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 17MB/28MB, paused 1.551ms total 134.531ms

--------- beginning of crash

01-18 10:16:31.658 F/libc    ( 3922): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8bcff78 passed to dlfree
01-18 10:16:31.658 F/libc    ( 3922): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 3934 (FinalizerDaemon)

----------------------------
01-18 10:29:41.371 I/art     ( 4123): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 130237(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(6MB) LOS objects, 36% free, 28MB/44MB, paused 1.372ms total 130.812ms

--------- beginning of crash

01-18 10:29:41.372 F/libc    ( 4123): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8eb7260 passed to dlfree
01-18 10:29:41.372 F/libc    ( 4123): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 4137 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

I added some detailed logs

```
--------- beginning of crash
12-16 20:05:53.069 F/libc    ( 8738): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8603590 passed to dlfree
12-16 20:05:53.070 F/libc    ( 8738): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 8749 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-18 23:03:14.972 F/libc    (24085): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb867d6f0 passed to dlfree
12-18 23:03:14.972 F/libc    (24085): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 24096 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-19 18:15:44.966 F/libc    (18334): heap corruption detected by tmalloc_small
12-19 18:15:44.967 F/libc    (18334): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 18355 (pool-2-thread-1)
12-20 22:20:15.447 F/libc    (20999): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb83ddf88 passed to dlfree
12-20 22:20:15.447 F/libc    (20999): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 21010 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665): Process: com.velocehq.veloce, PID: 26665
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665): android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) <0x9fafe37c + 0x00094> in <3eee3b55efe44f35867729db90edd0f2>:0 
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) <0x9fa9cfe4 + 0x000d3> in <3eee3b55efe44f35867729db90edd0f2>:0 
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):   at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) <0x9fcdc3fc + 0x000a7> in <0a564bf579e341ad971eb45b8e74ab94>:0 
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_intptr_intptr_bool_int_int_int_int(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPZIIII_V (_JniMarshal_PPZIIII_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.Boolean p0, System.Int32 p1, System.Int32 p2, System.Int32 p3, System.Int32 p4) [0x00005] in <0a564bf579e341ad971eb45b8e74ab94>:0 
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout(Native Method)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.onLayout(PlatformRenderer.java:58)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2098)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5259)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
12-21 13:09:59.671 E/AndroidRuntime(26665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
12-23 08:51:30.838 F/libc    ( 2021): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb86ddb68 passed to dlfree
12-23 08:51:30.838 F/libc    ( 2021): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 2032 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-24 08:00:30.417 F/libc    (15492): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x75 in tid 15505 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-24 17:16:08.711 F/libc    ( 4878): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb1cb9d8 passed to dlfree
12-24 17:16:08.711 F/libc    ( 4878): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 4889 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-24 17:16:08.837 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-24 17:16:08.838 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
12-24 17:16:08.839 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
12-24 17:16:08.841 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
12-24 17:16:08.843 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 4878, tid: 4889, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.pax.market.android.app <<<
12-24 17:16:08.844 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
12-24 17:16:08.894 I/DEBUG   (  313): Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb1cb9d8 passed to dlfree'
12-24 17:16:08.895 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 00000000  r1 b6e25dec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
12-24 17:16:08.896 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 0b1cb9d8  r5 b6e270f8  r6 9dee7000  r7 b8a27008
12-24 17:16:08.896 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 ffffffff  r9 b854b930  sl 2324ea90  fp 2339c6a0
12-24 17:16:08.896 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 01000000  sp b3ef2a98  lr b6df7dab  pc b6df7dac  cpsr 60070030
12-24 17:16:08.897 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
12-24 17:16:08.897 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
12-24 17:16:08.898 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 00028dac  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
12-24 17:16:08.898 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 0000f2ab  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
12-24 17:16:08.899 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 0008f877  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
12-24 17:16:08.899 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 0002a3cf  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_SESSION_free+146)
12-24 17:16:08.900 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 00017c0d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
12-24 17:16:09.015 I/DEBUG   (  313): ptrace attach to 4878 failed: Operation not permitted
12-24 23:18:19.827 F/libc    (27816): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6c656966 in tid 27827 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-25 20:21:55.686 F/libc    ( 2471): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x100476 passed to dlfree
12-25 20:21:55.686 F/libc    ( 2471): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 2482 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-26 21:20:24.605 F/libc    (12754): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8638020 passed to dlfree
12-26 21:20:24.606 F/libc    (12754): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 12765 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-28 10:27:42.439 F/libc    (17541): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x53184fe3 passed to dlfree
12-28 10:27:42.439 F/libc    (17541): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 17552 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-28 16:16:33.264 F/libc    (31822): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 31833 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-28 16:16:33.380 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-28 16:16:33.386 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
12-28 16:16:33.387 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
12-28 16:16:33.387 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
12-28 16:16:33.388 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 31822, tid: 31833, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.pax.market.android.app <<<
12-28 16:16:33.389 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
12-28 16:16:33.422 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 b8c0bf30  r1 00000000  r2 b8601848  r3 00000000
12-28 16:16:33.423 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b85f0bd8  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000003
12-28 16:16:33.424 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 b85f0bf8  r9 b8601848  sl b85d2b48  fp 23990dc0
12-28 16:16:33.424 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 00000001  sp b3ef6a80  lr b6cf89d7  pc b6cf89e8  cpsr 000f0030
12-28 16:16:33.425 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
12-28 16:16:33.425 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
12-28 16:16:33.426 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 000169e8  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so
12-28 16:16:33.426 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 00016a77  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android8ResTable6uninitEv+28)
12-28 16:16:33.427 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 00016ad1  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android8ResTableD1Ev+4)
12-28 16:16:33.427 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 0000ec0f  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android12AssetManagerD2Ev+38)
12-28 16:16:33.427 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 0000ec5d  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android12AssetManagerD0Ev+4)
12-28 16:16:33.428 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #05 pc 00081fdf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-28 16:16:33.428 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #06 pc 000003df  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
12-28 16:16:33.484 I/DEBUG   (  313): ptrace attach to 31822 failed: Operation not permitted
12-31 03:34:30.053 F/libc    ( 6253): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb865beb8 passed to dlfree
12-31 03:34:30.053 F/libc    ( 6253): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 6264 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-01 23:27:39.567 F/libc    ( 4555): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb85d1340 passed to dlfree
01-01 23:27:39.568 F/libc    ( 4555): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 4587 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-02 09:59:53.116 F/libc    (30823): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8736d80 passed to dlfree
01-02 09:59:53.117 F/libc    (30823): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 30834 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-02 23:17:17.809 F/libc    ( 1091): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8000005b in tid 3198 (OkHttp Connecti)
01-04 17:17:03.595 F/libc    ( 7580): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8ba8168 passed to dlfree
01-04 17:17:03.596 F/libc    ( 7580): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 7591 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-04 17:17:03.703 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-04 17:17:03.704 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
01-04 17:17:03.704 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
01-04 17:17:03.704 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
01-04 17:17:03.707 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 7580, tid: 7591, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.pax.market.android.app <<<
01-04 17:17:03.707 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
01-04 17:17:03.751 I/DEBUG   (  313): Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8ba8168 passed to dlfree'
01-04 17:17:03.752 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 00000000  r1 b6e25dec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
01-04 17:17:03.753 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b8ba8168  r5 b6e270f8  r6 a0ca2000  r7 b8ba8170
01-04 17:17:03.753 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 ffffffff  r9 b84d5aa8  sl 233196d0  fp 234d6fb0
01-04 17:17:03.754 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 00000000  sp b3ef6a98  lr b6df7dab  pc b6df7dac  cpsr 600f0030
01-04 17:17:03.755 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
01-04 17:17:03.755 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
01-04 17:17:03.755 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 00028dac  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
01-04 17:17:03.756 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 0000f2ab  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
01-04 17:17:03.756 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 0008f877  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
01-04 17:17:03.756 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 0002a3cf  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_SESSION_free+146)
01-04 17:17:03.757 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 00017c0d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
01-04 17:17:03.840 I/DEBUG   (  313): ptrace attach to 7580 failed: Operation not permitted
01-04 23:29:22.443 F/libc    (  709): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb86ee9e0 passed to dlfree
01-04 23:29:22.444 F/libc    (  709): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 721 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-05 22:36:09.997 F/libc    (30339): heap corruption detected by dlfree
01-05 22:36:09.998 F/libc    (30339): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30350 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-06 21:38:48.360 F/libc    (20475): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb85f9a00 passed to dlfree
01-06 21:38:48.361 F/libc    (20475): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 20486 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-08 11:58:54.165 F/libc    (19878): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8840440 passed to dlfree
01-08 11:58:54.166 F/libc    (19878): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 19889 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-09 22:20:31.403 F/libc    ( 3294): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9a038bcc in tid 3316 (pool-1-thread-1)
01-10 09:17:35.504 F/libc    ( 7356): heap corruption detected by dlfree
01-10 09:17:35.504 F/libc    ( 7356): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 7367 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-10 09:17:35.567 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-10 09:17:35.567 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
01-10 09:17:35.567 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
01-10 09:17:35.568 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
01-10 09:17:35.568 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 7356, tid: 7367, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.pax.market.android.app <<<
01-10 09:17:35.568 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-10 09:17:35.651 I/DEBUG   (  313): Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by dlfree'
01-10 09:17:35.652 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 00000000  r1 00001cc7  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
01-10 09:17:35.653 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b3ef6dd8  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
01-10 09:17:35.653 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 b6c8e714  r9 b84d5aa8  sl 2391b4f0  fp 23a04ce0
01-10 09:17:35.655 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 00001cc7  sp b3ef6a20  lr b6de2ac9  pc b6e09260  cpsr 600f0010
01-10 09:17:35.657 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
01-10 09:17:35.657 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
01-10 09:17:35.658 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 0003a260  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-10 09:17:35.659 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 00013ac5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
01-10 09:17:35.659 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 000146db  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-10 09:17:35.660 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 00010e7d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
01-10 09:17:35.660 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 0000f534  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-10 09:17:35.661 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #05 pc 000121b3  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16)
01-10 09:17:35.662 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #06 pc 00026999  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_heap_corruption_error+8)
01-10 09:17:35.663 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #07 pc 00028a0d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+312)
01-10 09:17:35.664 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #08 pc 0000f2ab  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
01-10 09:17:35.665 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #09 pc 0008f877  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
01-10 09:17:35.666 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #10 pc 0002a3cf  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_SESSION_free+146)
01-10 09:17:35.666 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #11 pc 00017c0d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
01-10 09:17:35.781 I/DEBUG   (  313): ptrace attach to 7356 failed: Operation not permitted
01-11 22:57:13.385 F/libc    ( 7160): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb86e18e8 passed to dlfree
01-11 22:57:13.385 F/libc    ( 7160): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 7173 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-15 04:18:13.668 F/libc    (28716): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8b5c788 passed to dlfree
01-15 04:18:13.668 F/libc    (28716): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 28730 (GCDaemon)
01-15 04:18:13.734 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-15 04:18:13.735 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
01-15 04:18:13.735 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
01-15 04:18:13.736 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
01-15 04:18:13.736 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 28716, tid: 28730, name: GCDaemon  >>> com.pax.market.android.app <<<
01-15 04:18:13.737 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
01-15 04:18:13.839 I/DEBUG   (  313): Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8b5c788 passed to dlfree'
01-15 04:18:13.839 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 00000000  r1 b6e25dec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
01-15 04:18:13.840 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b8b5c788  r5 b6e270f8  r6 9fd9b000  r7 b8b5c790
01-15 04:18:13.840 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 b4954fd9  r9 b83d7cd0  sl b4b1dc84  fp b83d7d18
01-15 04:18:13.841 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 00000000  sp a5c43480  lr b6df7dab  pc b6df7dac  cpsr 60070030
01-15 04:18:13.842 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
01-15 04:18:13.842 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
01-15 04:18:13.843 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 00028dac  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
01-15 04:18:13.843 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 0000f2ab  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
01-15 04:18:13.844 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 001e9a47  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11MonitorList16SweepMonitorListEPFPNS_6mirror6ObjectES3_PvES4_+142)
01-15 04:18:13.845 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 00212dcd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime16SweepSystemWeaksEPFPNS_6mirror6ObjectES3_PvES4_+24)
01-15 04:18:13.845 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 00123b6d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep12ReclaimPhaseEv+176)
01-15 04:18:13.846 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #05 pc 00127bb7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep9RunPhasesEv+102)
01-15 04:18:13.846 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #06 pc 0011f151  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+232)
01-15 04:18:13.847 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #07 pc 0013c867  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+1398)
01-15 04:18:13.847 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #08 pc 0013dc29  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadE+48)
01-15 04:18:13.848 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #09 pc 000003df  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
01-15 04:18:13.944 I/DEBUG   (  313): ptrace attach to 28716 failed: Operation not permitted
01-17 00:00:00.301 F/libc    (23575): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 23622 (RenderThread)
01-17 00:00:00.404 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-17 00:00:00.404 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
01-17 00:00:00.404 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
01-17 00:00:00.405 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
01-17 00:00:00.405 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 23575, tid: 23622, name: RenderThread  >>> com.velocehq.veloce <<<
01-17 00:00:00.405 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
01-17 00:00:00.499 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 b9e0c9b0  r1 00000000  r2 b6dce028  r3 9ed425fa
01-17 00:00:00.499 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b9c01dd8  r5 00000000  r6 b8bd8cd8  r7 00000000
01-17 00:00:00.499 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 b8bd8ce4  r9 9d6fbd28  sl 9d6fbd20  fp b8bd8d20
01-17 00:00:00.499 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip b69cda80  sp 9d6fbce0  lr b69be847  pc 00000000  cpsr 60070010
01-17 00:00:00.500 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
01-17 00:00:00.500 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
01-17 00:00:00.511 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
01-17 00:00:00.511 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 0003a845  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-17 00:00:00.511 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 0003adfb  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-17 00:00:00.512 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 0003bfe7  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-17 00:00:00.512 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 0003bf31  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-17 00:00:00.512 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #05 pc 0003c955  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-17 00:00:00.512 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #06 pc 0003d2d3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+66)
01-17 00:00:00.513 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #07 pc 0000ef55  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
01-17 00:00:00.513 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #08 pc 0005ca15  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+72)
01-17 00:00:00.513 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #09 pc 0000eac5  /system/lib/libutils.so
01-17 00:00:00.513 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #10 pc 000132b3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
01-17 00:00:00.513 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #11 pc 000111df  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
01-21 06:56:18.790 F/libc    ( 5067): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8899358 passed to dlfree
01-21 06:56:18.802 F/libc    ( 5067): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5078 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-21 06:56:18.920 I/DEBUG   (  313): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-21 06:56:18.921 I/DEBUG   (  313): Build fingerprint: 'PAX/CB03/CB03:5.1.1/LMY47V/CB03_CH_V4.70_S:user/release-keys'
01-21 06:56:18.922 I/DEBUG   (  313): Revision: '0'
01-21 06:56:18.923 I/DEBUG   (  313): ABI: 'arm'
01-21 06:56:18.925 I/DEBUG   (  313): pid: 5067, tid: 5078, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.velocehq.veloce <<<
01-21 06:56:18.926 I/DEBUG   (  313): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
01-21 06:56:19.005 I/DEBUG   (  313): Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8899358 passed to dlfree'
01-21 06:56:19.006 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r0 00000000  r1 b6e25dec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
01-21 06:56:19.007 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r4 b8899358  r5 b6e270f8  r6 8da7d000  r7 b8899360
01-21 06:56:19.008 I/DEBUG   (  313):     r8 00000000  r9 00000000  sl b943d1e0  fp 12efc840
01-21 06:56:19.009 I/DEBUG   (  313):     ip 00000000  sp b3ef4a40  lr b6df7dab  pc b6df7dac  cpsr 60070030
01-21 06:56:19.010 I/DEBUG   (  313): 
01-21 06:56:19.010 I/DEBUG   (  313): backtrace:
01-21 06:56:19.011 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #00 pc 00028dac  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
01-21 06:56:19.011 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #01 pc 0000f2ab  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
01-21 06:56:19.012 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #02 pc 0008f877  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
01-21 06:56:19.012 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #03 pc 0004fe3b  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-21 06:56:19.013 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #04 pc 0004da15  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-21 06:56:19.013 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #05 pc 0004da15  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-21 06:56:19.014 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #06 pc 0004d969  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (ASN1_item_free+12)
01-21 06:56:19.014 I/DEBUG   (  313):     #07 pc 00017c0d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Comment: What is your app doing?  Are you using the NDK for anything in there?

Comment: No use of ndk. most of the time it seems to happen is when doing network communication